Applying Shell Launcher configuration via the official Powershell script fails
I need to configure Shell Launcher for some PCs. I am testing the configuration in one computer at the moment. I have followed the official, Microsoft Documentation, created the .xml file and now I need to apply the settings to the PC.
I need to use Powershell and apply them to one computer for testing at the moment.
The official script from the docs is this:
$shellLauncherConfiguration = @"

# content of the XML configuration file

"@

$namespaceName="root\cimv2\mdm\dmmap"
$className="MDM_AssignedAccess"
$obj = Get-CimInstance -Namespace $namespaceName -ClassName $className
$obj.Configuration = [System.Net.WebUtility]::HtmlEncode($shellLauncherConfiguration)
$obj = Set-CimInstance -CimInstance $obj -ErrorVariable cimSetError -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if($cimSetError) {
    Write-Output "An ERROR occurred. Displaying error record and attempting to retrieve error logs...`n"
    Write-Error -ErrorRecord $cimSetError[0]

    $timeout = New-TimeSpan -Seconds 30
    $stopwatch = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
    do{
        $events = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $eventLogFilterHashTable -ErrorAction Ignore
    } until ($events.Count -or $stopwatch.Elapsed -gt $timeout) # wait for the log to be available

    if($events.Count) {
        $events | ForEach-Object {
            Write-Output "$($_.TimeCreated) [$($_.LevelDisplayName.ToUpper())] $($_.Message -replace "`n|`r")"
        }
    } else {
        Write-Warning "Timed-out attempting to retrieve event logs..."
    }

    Exit 1
}

Write-Output "Successfully applied Shell Launcher configuration"

As you can see this is already broken since $eventLogFilterHashTable is not even defined anywhere. I have eliminated that FilterHashtable argument and the script runs, but fails without any useful error.
C:\Users\admin\Downloads\ApplyShellLauncher.ps1 : A general error occurred that is not covered by a more specific error code.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\ApplyShellLauncher.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MDM_AssignedAcc..../Vendor/MSFT"):CimInstance) [Write-Error], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MI RESULT 1,ApplyShellLauncher.ps1

I am stuck here and no idea what to do. I have tested the first example script here to see if WMI Bridge Provider was working and that script works.
More info:

Yes I am running Powershell as SYSTEM with psexec.exe -i -s powershell.exe
Just to be sure I am also using a local Admin account since usually our accounts come from LDAP
Yes the .xml is valid


In your actual script you configured $shellLauncherConfiguration to be set to the string that contains the XML you wanted to apply.  The script is failing to run due to the first line, $shellLauncherConfiguration, is the variable on the first line.  This suggests the problem is contained within the string itself.

@Ramhound Yes I did set the XML I want to apply in the first variable. Also I have validated it and it is a valid XML file. I don't know why the error is throwing at line 1, but it is not true. The error actually throws at
Set-CimInstance -CimInstance $obj.
When I remove this line, the script completes (obviously does not do anything useful).

I have finally solved this problem, and it is due the atrocious and wrong Microsoft documentation. The script posted in the official docs is wrong. This works:
[string]$shellLauncherConfiguration = Get-Content '.\ShellLauncherConfig.xml'
$namespaceName="root\cimv2\mdm\dmmap"
$className="MDM_AssignedAccess"
$obj = Get-CimInstance -Namespace $namespaceName -ClassName $className
$obj.ShellLauncher = [System.Net.WebUtility]::HtmlEncode($shellLauncherConfiguration)
$obj = Set-CimInstance -CimInstance $obj -ErrorVariable cimSetError -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if($cimSetError) {
    Write-Output "An ERROR occurred. Displaying error record and attempting to retrieve error logs...`n"
    Write-Error -ErrorRecord $cimSetError[0]

    $timeout = New-TimeSpan -Seconds 30
    $stopwatch = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
    $eventLogFilterHashTable=@{ LogName='Microsoft-Windows-AssignedAccess/Admin' }
    do{
        $events = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $eventLogFilterHashTable -ErrorAction Ignore
    } until ($events.Count -or $stopwatch.Elapsed -gt $timeout) # wait for the log to be available

    if($events.Count) {
        $events | ForEach-Object {
            Write-Output "$($_.TimeCreated) [$($_.LevelDisplayName.ToUpper())] $($_.Message -replace "`n|`r")"
        }
    } else {
        Write-Warning "Timed-out attempting to retrieve event logs..."
    }

    Exit 1
}

Write-Output "Successfully applied Shell Launcher configuration"

The configuration must be set in the ShellLauncher property, and not in Configuration like in the official docs:
$obj.ShellLauncher = [System.Net.WebUtility]::HtmlEncode($shellLauncherConfiguration)

The variable eventLogFilterHashTable was undefined. This should be defined like this to catch the errors from the Windows Events:
$eventLogFilterHashTable=@{ LogName='Microsoft-Windows-AssignedAccess/Admin' }

I am now also loading the configuration directly from the xml file instead of copy-pasting the content:
[string]$shellLauncherConfiguration = Get-Content '.\ShellLauncherConfig.xml'

